# Access xsd file in WebContent folder from a MessageBodyReader class

Tags: java, xsd, jax-rs, getresource, web-content

Inside a JAX-RS service I wan't to provide a `XmlValidatonReader` which validates incoming XML documents against an exising xsd file which is located in the `WebContent` directory.

[image]

The xsd file needs to be inside the `WebContent` folder because it should be accessible to the client. In order to validate the incoming XML file I need the xsd resource: `/WebContent/Category.xsd`

How can I load this from `src/at/fhj/ase/XmlValidationReader.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I brought it to run.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class XmlValidationReader implements MessageBodyReader<Category> {

    protected Providers providers;
    protected ServletContext servletContext;
    private final String xsdFileName = "/Category.xsd";
    private Schema schema;

    public XmlValidationReader(@Context Providers providers,
            @Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.providers = providers;
        this.servletContext = servletContext;

        try {
            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory
                    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            File xsd = new File(servletContext.getRealPath(xsdFileName));
            schema = sf.newSchema(xsd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to create XSD validation schema", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        ...
    }


    @Override
    public Category readFrom(Class<Category> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        ...
    }
```